# Match texts from list with json property SPacy

Tags: python, json, spacy

I am trying to match texts that are stored in list with json property from json file.
So far I managed to match it 1:1 which means that the text from the json and from the list must be exact same which is not desirable or useful...

Example:
`messages.json`

```
[
 {
    "id": "1",
    "task_id": "1",
    "team": "Top",
    "message": "Failure indicated something else [gdfgdfgg]",
  },
 {
    "id": "2",
    "task_id": "2",
    "team": "Ten",
    "message": "Internal server error 500 something else [dasdasdasdasdas]",
  }
]
```

So from that JSON I would like to match only the property `message` with `Failure indicated` and `Internal server error 500` without the text after it, having a lot of these messages so cannot replace all of them one by one.

What I tried so far:

```
import json
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

message_list = ['Failure indicated','Internal server error 500']

def matching_data(data):
   nlp= English()
   extract_data: list = [msg["message"] for msg in data]
   
   matcher= PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
   patterns= [nlp.make_doc(msg) for msg in extract_data]
   matcher.add("Messages", None, *patterns)

   match_check= any([item in extract_data for item in message_list])
    if not match_check:
        print("No matches found")
    else:
        for msg in message_list:
            doc= nlp(msg)
            for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
                print("Message matched based on lowercase token text:", doc[start:end])

matching_data(json.loads(open("messages.json").read()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher) on how to add patterns to the PhraseMatcher. First, add the phrases from your `message_list` to the PhraseMatcher and then find these patterns in the list of messages extracted from your json file.

```
import json
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

with open('messages.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    extract_data = [msg["message"] for msg in data]

nlp = English()
matcher= PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
message_list = ['Failure indicated', 'Internal server error 500']
# add the multi-token phrases that you want to find to the PhraseMatcher  
patterns = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in message_list]
matcher.add("MessageList", None, *patterns)

for msg in extract_data:
    doc = nlp(msg)
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        print("Matched based on lowercase token text:", doc[start:end])
```

Comment: Thank you, Dora the Explorer!